# Track Application Usage Using Psutil on Windows

Tags: python, windows, automation, psutil

How would I use Psutil to track the applications I have open/using, does Psutil have a function that tells you all the applications that are running? I want to use it to track the time I spend on an application on my windows laptop.

Comment: This question is far too broad and not really about programming. It definitely doesn't appear to be about Python. What have you tried so far? What problems are you running into? Please share some of your code and explain what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I want to write a script that tracks the amount of time I spend on an application, A lot of people told me to use Psutil but I don't know if Psutil can monitor what applications are open on a windows system.

Comment: Have you read the basic documentation of psutil? https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes Have you tried importing it and played around with it? Have you specifically tried looking at listing and tracking running processes?